# Yii can't save data - unknown method save()

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2-advanced-app

Hello I am new to Yii framework and I am trying to save data to database. It won't work I don't know where is the problem.

Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Client;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class ClientController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Displays Client_Register.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAdd() {
        $model = new Client();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ($model->save()) {
                return $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        return $this->render('add', ['model' => $model,]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lastname') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'birthday') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'add-button']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Model:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Client is the model behind the client form.
 */
class Client extends Model {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $lastname;
    public $birthday;

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'clients';
    }

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['name', 'lastname', 'birthday',], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'Id',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'lastname' => 'Last Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

I have already created the database with migrations. But I don't why does this error happen. Should I include some save method in model or how can I solve this issue. I looked at other examples too. They are identical as my code. Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have some errors? try to var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()). PS in your model try to remove the variable you defined for example _public $id_ should overwrite the property $id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Client` class extends `Model`, which does not support saving data in database, thus `save()` method is not defined. If you want to work with database record, your model should extend [`ActiveRecord`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord):

```
class Client extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'clients';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['name', 'lastname', 'birthday'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'Id',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'lastname' => 'Last Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i include ActiveRecord in my project? because I got this error
ActiveRecord not found

Comment: Try to use FQN: `class Client extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord`.

Comment: I also suggest to generate model with Gii if you're starting with Yii - it will generate base model for you: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii#generating-ar